# how many stars have been recognized?

Tags: stars

I have wanted to ask this question for ever. I realize that the numbers are still ticking up but i just want a number from last year or something.

Comment: This would be a better question for http://astronomy.stackexchange.com , but I can't migrate it because it is too low quality. What do you mean "recognized"?

Comment: Some possibly related questions at Astronomy: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1083/6 and http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1018/6

Comment: http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad has cataloged nearly one billion objects, but is known to be far from complete.

Comment: thx for telling me